# Node.js and Express: wait for asynchronous operation before responding to HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

Say there is a HTTP GET callback defined as:

```
router.get('/latestpost', function(req, res, next) {

    var data = new FbData();
    get_latest_post (data);
    get_post_image (data);

    res.json(data);
};
```

Both `get_` functions use the [fb package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) to generate a HTTP request and execute a callback when finished. How can the above GET callback be modified in order to wait for the responses from Facebook and only then send a response to the client?

At the time being I solved the problem by executing the `get_` functions in series and passing them the `res` (response) argument, with the last function sending the response:

```
router.get('/latestpost', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = new FbData();
    get_latest_post (res, data);
};


function get_latest_post (res, data) {

    FB.api(_url, function (res_fb) {

        if(!res_fb || res_fb.error) {
            console.log(!res_fb ? 'error occurred' : res_fb.error);
            return;
        }

        // Do stuff with data

        get_post_image (res, data);
    });
}


function get_post_image (res, data) {

    FB.api(_url, function (res_fb) {

        if(!res_fb || res_fb.error) {
            console.log(!res_fb ? 'error occurred' : res_fb.error);
            return;
        }

        // Do stuff with data

        /* At the end send the post data to the client */
        res.json(data);
    });
}
```

I have found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838037/node-js-and-express-how-to-return-response-after-asynchronous-operation), but I'm wrapping my head around it, since I can't find a proper way to apply the solution to my problem. I have tried using the patterns described [in this manual](https://nodejs.dev/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await), but I can't get it to execute using promises, or async/await. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your API can easily be modified to return a promise:

```
 function get_post_image (res, data) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    FB.api(_url, function (res_fb) {
      if(!res_fb || res_fb.error) {
        reject(res_fb && res_fb.error);
      } else resolve(res_fb/*?*/);
   });
 }
```

Now that you have a promise, you can await it:

```
 router.get('/latestpost', async function(req, res, next) {
   const data = new FbData();
   const image = await get_post_image (data);

   res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: Would be good to wrap the `await` in a `try` and pass the caught error to `next()` so you don't have uncaught rejected promises. You can't use `util.callbackify()` though because it would call `next()` with two arguments on success which is not desired.

Comment: You _could_ define `const callbackify = fn => Object.defineProperty(
  (...args) => fn(...args.slice(0, -1)).catch(args.pop()),
  'length', { value: fn.length + 1, configurable: true }
);` to deal with the way express infers the type of middleware based on the function's arity, and avoid having to explicitly `try...catch` in each `async` middleware.

Comment: Very true. I might consider that for my next project.

Comment: @patrick I admit I also haven't used it that much yet ... I'm mostly using Express with some self-baked wrappers around it ...